# Add border-radius and padding to a single Table Row

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablerow

I can't seem to be able to add a border-radius and some padding on the side to a table row `tr`.

This is the effect I am trying to achieve:

[image]

But this is where I really am:

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div id="working_hours_pop">
    <table>
     <tr><td class="day">Понеделник</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Вторник</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Среда</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Четврток</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr id="current"><td class="day">Петок</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Сабота</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Недела</td><td id="sun">Затворено</td></tr> 
  </table>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
    html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table {
        position: relative; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
        width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0;               
        border: 0px yellow solid;
    }

html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop {
                    position: absolute; float: none; clear: both; top: 0; right: -350px;
                    width: 310px; height: auto; margin: -80px auto 0; padding: 15px 10px;
                    font-weight: 700; font-size: 12px;

                    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
                    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2.98px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
                    background-color: rgba(45, 138, 191, 0.95);
                    z-index: 20;
                }

        html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td { padding: 3px 0; }
        html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td.day { width: 90px; text-align: left; }
        html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td.time { width: 200px; text-align: right; }
        html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td.time span { padding: 0 18px; }
        html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td#sun { width: 200px; text-align: center; }

        html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table tr#current {
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
            border: 1px solid;
            background-color: rgba(25, 60, 88, 0.95);
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this even possible?

I tried adding a `div` inside the `tr` and styling that instead to achieve what I'm after. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `display: block;` to all `tr`'s and that fixed my problem.

Heres the CSS:

```
html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop {
                    position: absolute; float: none; clear: both; top: 0; right: -295px;
                    width: 300px; height: auto; margin: -79px auto 0; padding: 15px 10px;
                    font-weight: 700; font-size: 12px;

                    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
                    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2.98px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
                    background-color: rgba(45, 138, 191, 0.95);
                    z-index: 20;
                }
                html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop:after{
                    content: "";
                    position: absolute; float: none; clear: both; display: block; top: 90px; left: -8px;
                    width: 0; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;

                    border-style: solid; border-width: 15px 10px 15px 0;
                    border-color: transparent rgba(45, 135, 187, 1) transparent transparent;
                }
                    html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table {
                        position: relative; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
                        width: 250; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0;
                    }
                        html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td { padding: 3px 0; border: 0px green solid; }
                            html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td.day { width: 100px; text-align: left; }
                                html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td.day_sun { width: 145px; text-align: left; }

                            html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td.time { width: 200px; text-align: right; }
                                html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td.time span { padding: 0 18px; }
                            html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table td#sun { width: 200px; text-align: center; }

                        html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table tr {
                            display: block;
                            width: 280px; padding: 0 10px;
                        }
                        html body div#sidebar_panel div#sidebar_cnt div#working_hours div#working_hours_pop table tr#current {
                            -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
                            border: 0px solid; margin: 1px 1px; padding: 2px 8px; 
                            background-color: rgba(25, 60, 88, 0.65); font-weight: 600;
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your table has its borders collapsed: `border-collapse: collapse;`
2. Set a background colour on all of the cells in `tr#current`
3. Set a padding left on every `td:first`
4. Set a padding right on every `td:last`
5. Set a top left and bottom left border radius on every `tr#current td:first`
6. Set a top right and bottom right border radius on every `tr#current td:last`

Here is the modified CSS/HTML, note that I have removed some of your unnecessary selectors from the CSS for easy reading.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o44hpx39/

HTML:

```
<div id="working_hours_pop">
    <table>
     <tr><td class="day">Понеделник</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Вторник</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Среда</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Четврток</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr id="current"><td class="day">Петок</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Сабота</td><td class="time">од 8:00ч<span>—</span>до 19:00ч</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="day">Недела</td><td id="sun">Затворено</td></tr> 
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#working_hours_pop table {
    position: relative; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
    width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0;               
    border: 0px yellow solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

div#working_hours_pop table td { padding: 3px 0; }
div#working_hours_pop table td.day { width: 90px; text-align: left; }
div#working_hours_pop table td.time { width: 200px; text-align: right; }
div#working_hours_pop table td.time span { padding: 0 18px; }
div#working_hours_pop table td#sun { width: 200px; text-align: center; }

div#working_hours_pop table tr#current td { background-color: rgba(25, 60, 88, 0.95); }
div#working_hours_pop table tr td:first-child { padding-left: 10px; }
div#working_hours_pop table tr td:last-child { padding-right: 10px; }

div#working_hours_pop table tr#current td:first-child {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
            border-top-left-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

div#working_hours_pop table tr#current td:last-child {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
            border-top-right-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply `border-radius` to `tr` elements, only `td` and `table`, and maybe a few others, but I haven't tested them, but certainly not `tr`.

Here's an alternative solution that makes the first cell and last cell of each row have a border radius and gives the illusion that the whole row has a border radius:

```
#current td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#current td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```